# Xamarin.Forms SelectedItem of Region list

Tags: listview, xamarin, region

I have a problem with taking value from listView of type RegionModel. Here is my code.In constructor:

listView.ItemsSource = GetCountryList();

listView.ItemTapped += this.RegionChosen;

and methods:

public void GetCountries()

```
    {

        var regions = Common.GetRegions();
        RegionModel regionModel = SettingsService.RegionModel;
        listView.ItemsSource = regions;
      
    }
```

RegionChosen method:

public void RegionChosen(object sender, EventArgs e){

```
        var region = (RegionModel)listView.SelectedItem;
        SettingsService.SetRegion(region);


     }
```

In locals I have region as:  {{projekt}.Views.Environment.Region}

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are not using the correct signature for an `ItemTapped` handler

```
public void RegionChosen(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
{
    var region = (RegionModel)e.Item;
    SettingsService.SetRegion(region);
}
```